# User receives some but not all Scheduled Reports

Tags: reporting, scheduled

One of my users was complaining that he did not receive some of his scheduled reports (reports he scheduled himself with recipients either himself or himself+others). These reports had previously been received just fine.

- The system admin (me) received no emails from Salesforce indicating that the report(s) in question could not be run
- The reports were listed as scheduled in `Setup | Scheduled Jobs`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports in question had been successfully received as late as one week ago by User `U`

Several diagnostics were performed:

- Had company Spam filters been changed? **NO**
- Had the report actually been sent to the recipient by checking Salesforce Email Logs? **YES**
- If I added myself as a recipient to the report that was alleged to not be received, did I receive the report? **YES**
- Had a Salesforce max scheduled reporting limit been breached? **NO**

### And the answer was ...

The user `U` had added mail forwarding filters for the report(s) in question to send the report to other users but had not configured the filter to allow the received emailed report to remain in user `U's` mailbox. That is, the reports forwarded out fine but the filtering rule stopped processing the mail from even entering `U's` inbox.  Mail system was Zimbra.